# New document is not opening in word application with content in word addin development - React js

Tags: reactjs, ms-word, office-addins

Below is the code

```
  Word.run(function (context) { var myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument();

  context.load(myNewDoc);
  return context.sync()
      .then(function () {

          var myParagraph = myNewDoc.body.insertText('Hello', "start");
          myParagraph.font.bold = false;
          myParagraph.font.name = "Times New Roman";
          myNewDoc.open();
          context.sync();
      }) })
```

Please help me to get out of this